# Rotate a particular image only in canvas when left or right key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to canvas and developing a game where a car moves straight and now I want to rotate the image of the car only to rotate anti clockwise when the left key is pressed and clockwise when right key is pressed.

Currently I am trying with

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "images/car.png";
  if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.drawImage(heroImage,hero.x,hero.y);    
}
```

But this rotates the whole screen .I only want the heroImage to be rotated and not the screen.Any help is appreciated.
My source code: [working pen](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/)

Comment: Check this out: http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/

Comment: The link is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get key input and rotate paths and what not on the canvas.

```js
/** SimpleUpdate.js begin **/
// short cut vars 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
ctx.font = "18px arial";
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var focused = false;
var rotated = false;
var angle = 0;

// Handle all key input
const keys = {  // key input object
    ArrowLeft : false,  // only add key names you want to listen to
    ArrowRight : false,
    keyEvent (event) {
        if (keys[event.code] !== undefined) {  // are we interested in this key
            keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";
            rotated = true; // to turn off help
        }
    }
}
// add key listeners
document.addEventListener("keydown", keys.keyEvent)
document.addEventListener("keyup", keys.keyEvent)

// check if focus click
canvas.addEventListener("click",()=>focused = true);

// main update function
function update (timer) {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // reset transform
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);      
    
    // draw outside box
    ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, w - 100, h - 100);
    
    // rotate if input
    angle += keys.ArrowLeft ? -0.1 : 0;
    angle += keys.ArrowRight ? 0.1 : 0;
    
    // set orgin to center of canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
    
    // rotate
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    
    // draw rotated box
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
    ctx.fillRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
    
    // set transform to center
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
    // rotate
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    // move to corner
    ctx.translate(50,50);
    // rotate once more, Doubles the rotation
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow"
    ctx.fillRect(-20, -20,40, 40);

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // restore default
    
    // draw center box
    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
    ctx.fillRect(cw - 25, ch - 25, 50, 50);
    
    if(!focused){
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.strokeText("Click on canvas to get focus.",10,20);
        ctx.fillText("Click on canvas to get focus.",10,20);
    }else if(!rotated){
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.strokeText("Left right arrow to rotate.",10,20);
        ctx.fillText("Left right arrow to rotate.",10,20);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);

}
requestAnimationFrame(update);


/** SimpleUpdate.js end **/
```

```html
<canvas id = canvas></canvas>
```

Looking at you pen bellow is a function that will help.

The following function will draw a scaled and rotated sprite on the canvas

```
// draws a image as sprite at x,y scaled and rotated around its center 
// image, the image to draw
// x,y position of the center of the image 
// scale the scale, 1 no scale, < 1 smaller, > 1 larger
// angle in radians
function drawSprite(image, x, y, scale = 1,angle = 0){
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y); // set scale and center of sprite
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.drawImage(image,- image.width / 2, - image.height / 2);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restore default transform
                                   // if you call this function many times
                                   // and dont do any other rendering between
                                   // move the restore default line
                                   // outside this function and after all the
                                   // sprites are drawn. 
}
```

OK more for you.

Your code is all over the place and the only way to work out what was happening was to rewrite it from the ground up.

The following does what I think you want your pen to do. Not I squash the width to fit the snippet window.

Code from [OP pen](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/) and modified to give what I think the OP wants.

```js
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 1024;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var monstersCaught = 0;
var lastFrameTime;
var frameTime = 0;  // in seconds used to control hero speed

// The main game loop
function main (time) {
    if(lastFrameTime !== undefined){
        frameTime = (time - lastFrameTime) / 1000;  // in seconds
    }
    lastFrameTime = time
    updateObjects();
   render();
   requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// this is called when all the images have loaded
function start(){
    monstersCaught = 0;
    resetObjs();
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
function displayStatus(message){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // set default transform
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
   ctx.textAlign = "center";
   ctx.textBaseline = "center";
   ctx.fillText(message,canvas.width / 2 ,canvas.height / 2);
}
// reset objects
function resetObjs () {
    monsters.array.forEach(monster => monster.reset());
    heros.array.forEach(hero => hero.reset());
}

// Update game objects
function updateObjects (modifier) {

    monsters.array.forEach(monster => monster.update());
    heros.array.forEach(hero => hero.update());
}

function drawObjects (modifier) {
    monsters.array.forEach(monster => monster.draw());
    heros.array.forEach(hero => hero.draw());
    
}

// Draw everything
function render () {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // set default transform
    ctx.drawImage(images.background, 0, 0);    
    drawObjects();

 // Score
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // set default transform
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
   ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
   ctx.textAlign = "left";
   ctx.textBaseline = "top";
   ctx.fillText("Points: " + monstersCaught, 32, 32);
}

// hold all the images in one object.
const images = {  // double underscore __ is to prevent adding images that replace these functions
    __status : {
        count : 0,
        ready : false,
        error : false,
    },
    __onready : null,
    __createImage(name,src){
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = src;
        images.__status.count += 1;
        image.onerror = function(){
            images.__status.error = true;
            displayStatus("Error loading image : '"+ name + "'");
        }
        image.onload = function(){
            images.__status.count -= 1;
            if(images.__status.count === 0){
                images.__status.ready = true;
                images.__onready();
            }
            if(!images.__status.error){
                displayStatus("Images remaing : "+ images.__status.count);
            }
        }
        images[name] = image;
        return image;
    }
}

// Handle all key input
const keys = {  // key input object
    ArrowLeft : false,  // only add key names you want to listen to
    ArrowRight : false,
    ArrowDown : false,
    ArrowUp : false,
    keyEvent (event) {
        if (keys[event.code] !== undefined) {  // are we interested in this key
            keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}

// default setting for objects
const objectDefault = {
    x : 0, y : 0,
    dir : 0,  // the image rotation
    isTouching(obj){  // returns true if object is touching box x,y,w,h
        return !(this.x > obj.x +obj.w || this.y > obj.y +obj.h || this.x + this.w < obj.x || this.y + this.h < obj.y);
    },
    draw(){
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,this.x + this.w / 2, this.y + this.h / 2);
        ctx.rotate(this.dir); 
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, - this.image.width / 2, - this.image.height / 2);
    },
    reset(){},
    update(){},
}

// default setting for monster object
const monsterDefault = {
    w : 32, // width 
    h : 32, // height
    reset(){
        this.x = this.w + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - this.w * 2));        
        this.y = this.h + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - this.h * 2));        
    },
}

// default settings for hero
const heroDefault = {
    w : 32, // width 
    h : 32, // height
    speed : 256,
    spawnPos : 1.5,
    reset(){
        this.x = canvas.width /  this.spawnPos;
        this.y = canvas.height / this.spawnPos;        
    }, 
    update(){
        if (keys.ArrowUp) { // Player holding up
            this.y -= this.speed * frameTime;
            this.dir = Math.PI * 0; // set direction
        }
        if (keys.ArrowDown) { // Player holding down
            this.y += this.speed * frameTime;
            this.dir = Math.PI * 1; // set direction
       }
       if (keys.ArrowLeft) { // Player holding left
            this.x -= this.speed * frameTime;
            this.dir = Math.PI * 1.5; // set direction
        }
        if (keys.ArrowRight) { // Player holding right
            this.x += this.speed * frameTime;
            this.dir = Math.PI * 0.5; // set direction
        }        
        if(Math.sign(this.speed) === -1){ // filp directio of second car
            this.dir += Math.PI; // set direction
        }
        
        monsters.array.forEach(monster => {
            if(monster.isTouching(this)){
                monster.reset();
                monstersCaught += 1;
            }
        });
        if (this.x >= canvas.width || this.y >= canvas.height || this. y < 0 || this.x < 0) {
            this.reset();
        } 
    }
}

// objects to hold monsters and heros
const monsters = { // dont call a monster "array"
    array : [],  // copy of monsters as array    
};

const heros = { // dont call a monster "array"
    array : [], // copy of heros as array
};

// add monster 
function createMonster(name, settings = {}){
    monsters[name] = {...objectDefault, ...monsterDefault, ...settings, name};
    monsters[name].reset();
    monsters.array.push(monsters[name]);
    return monsters[name];
}

// add hero to heros object
function createHero(name, settings){
    heros[name] = {...objectDefault, ...heroDefault, ...settings, name};
    heros[name].reset();
    heros.array.push(heros[name]);
    return heros[name];
}

// set function to call when all images have loaded
images.__onready = start;

// load all the images
images.__createImage("background", "http://res.cloudinary.com/dfhppjli0/image/upload/v1491958481/road_lrjihy.jpg");
images.__createImage("hero", "http://res.cloudinary.com/dfhppjli0/image/upload/c_scale,w_32/v1491958999/car_p1k2hw.png");
images.__createImage("monster", "http://res.cloudinary.com/dfhppjli0/image/upload/v1491959220/m_n1rbem.png");

// create all objects
createHero("hero", {image : images.hero, spawnPos : 1.5});
createHero("hero3", {image : images.hero, spawnPos : 2, speed : -256});
createMonster("monster", {image : images.monster});
createMonster("monster3", {image : images.monster});
createMonster("monster9", {image : images.monster});
createMonster("monster12", {image : images.monster});

// add key listeners
document.addEventListener("keydown", keys.keyEvent);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keys.keyEvent);
```

```css
canvas {
   width : 100%;
   height : 100%;
}
```

Comment: My [working pen](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/)  also has ctx.rotate() but why  is it not rotating?Could you help me?

Comment: @Josh I have added a function (to answer) that will draw a sprite for you. Your pen has a lot of code which is to much to address at the moment.

Comment: I added ur function into my code and I replaced the  `if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
  drawSprite(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y, scale = 1,angle = 90)  
}`  .  But now no changes are happening and no errors are also not thrown.

Comment: @Josh I Have looked at your pen in more detail. For me to understand it I had to rewrite it, I have added what I think you want in my answer. You had a lot of repeated code and no consistent structure so I redesigned your code to be easier to expand upon, though it may be a bit complex. Do ask questions if you need and I will see if I can help when I get time.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and the structured code. I tried to run it but it throws an error at  `   monsters[name] = {...objectDefault, ...monsterDefault, ...settings, name};`.May I know what is the `...objectDefault` refering for?

Comment: @Josh Could be that you are using IE? I have turned on babel.js which I forgot to do that will fix any ES6 problems with older or incompatible browsers. If you are you running it in code pen you will have to set up babel. If that does not work and you are using a modern browser try `monsters[name] = Object.assign({}, objectDefault, monsterDefault, settings, {name});` Same for heros

Comment: @ Blindman67 I was using chrome and Yeah the above change worked fine.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Josh Forgot to tell you what objectDefault is for. That holds all the common default properties shared between the monsters and heros, monsterDefault and heroDefault hold the default properties for monsters and heros respectively. From left to right the properties are added overwriting any of the defaults. Settings object overwrites all eg `{speed : -256}` for the second car. And name is just a referance so if you need to know what the object is you can test the name `if(heros.array[i].name === "hero3")` You can also access the objects via the name `heros.hero3` is the second car

Comment: Oh now I get it so this  properties can be customized by overwriting any of the defaults of  the hero and the monster.Tons of thanks for the explanation